# With which command in "Terminal" can I connect to internet?

Tags: networking

I errased some Ubuntu programs in Ubuntu 10.4 and now I just can work with "Terminal".

All my directories are still there but I wish to recover the graphical presentation.

But because I need the internet to download some programs, a terminal-command is asked.

Thanks.

Comment: You should be already connected to the internet. Try `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: `sakis3g` will help you to connect to the internet.

Comment: I'd suggest you upgrade 10.04 is not supported any more except the server which does not have a GUI. Backup all your personal data then install either [Xubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) or [Ubuntu 12.04 LTS](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) depending on your hardware: Xubuntu is more like Ubuntu used to be and runs on older hardware.  You can try them both from a live USB and install the one you prefer.

Comment: @searchfgold6789 Impressive if you can do that without an internet connection.

Comment: Maybe is time to download an the ISO and reinstall (**after doing backups**). It will be faster and bandwidth cheaper (you don't have to install all your packages to then upgrade Ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Hit alt+ctrl+f1 and login to your system with your existing account.

All terminals are by default can access to the internet if your pc is connected. for your confirmation you can ping any server like

```
ping google.com
```

if  you get some response then you are connected to the internet. now you can download and install your required software.

Comment: +1 - internet connection is configured during boot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a text-only browser like **elinks** to browse in text mode via the command line.

`sudo apt-get install elinks`